# glTexParameter on Android -> OpenGL Error

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a strange problem when using the above mentioned method:

```
gl.glTexParameterx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
```

While this works great on the Android emulator I get an Open GL error on the actual device (samsung galaxy). The error is `GL_INVALID_VALUE` (Code `0x501`).

Why is that?

Comment: As you're new here, be sure to inform yourself about the accept and up-vote features.

Answer (score 3):

`GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` doesn't take [anything other than `GL_NEAREST` or `GL_LINEAR`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glTexParameter.xml)